# Ignoring null fields when deserializing with Jackson

Tags: jackson, kotlin

I have the following Kotlin data class:

```
data class TestObject(
        val boolField: Boolean,
        val stringField: String,
        val nullBoolField: Boolean = true,
        val nullStringField: String = "default",
        val notThereBoolField: Boolean = true,
        val notThereStringField: String = "not there"
)
```

I am then attempting to deserialize some JSON into this class using Jackson v2.9.4 with the Jackson Kotlin plugin v2.9.4.1. The test JSON is as follows:

```
{
    "boolField": true,
    "stringField": "string",
    "nullBoolField": null,
    "nullStringField": null
}
```

The first two and the last two fields deserialize successfully - with the values from the JSON and the default values from the Kotlin data class, as appropriate. However, when the middle pair of fields are present, the deserialization fails with:

> Instantiation of [simple type, class com.example.TestObject] value
>   failed for JSON property nullStringField due to missing (therefore
>   NULL) value for creator parameter nullStringField which is a
>   non-nullable type

I know I *could* solve the problem by changing the types of `nullBoolField` and `nullStringField` to `Boolean?` and `String?` respectively, but since default values are known I would rather not have to push the handling of `null` further down into the code by doing that.

The question is: is there any way of configuring Jackson to use the Kotlin data class default values for non-nullable properties when the property is present in the JSON but set to null?

Comment: Did you find any answer on it, I still have the same issue, and i can't resolve it at the moment...?

Answer (score 1):

You could try first to filter null values from `json` and after to deserialize it to Kotlin object.

Or you may to try add feature to `kotlin-jackson` module, with adding a new feature parameter, which will enable a null ignoring from json parameters and use default values. 
You may do this by modify this [line](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/kotlin/KotlinValueInstantiator.kt#L41) (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: `you may to try add feature to kotlin-jackson module, with adding a new feature parameter, which will enable a null ignoring from json parameters and use default values`. How would that work? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any value and field is non-nullable then you should not pass it in request body:

```
{
    "boolField": true,
    "stringField": "string"
}
```

This results in following object, as expected:

```
{
    "boolField": true,
    "stringField": "string",
    "nullBoolField": true,
    "nullStringField": "default",
    "notThereBoolField": true,
    "notThereStringField": "not there"
}
```

Comment: That would be the easy way out I agree. However, in this case, I don't control the source JSON so am trying to find a way to get the intended result when deserializing.

Comment: @George in such situation you could use a DTO and then create TestObject based on its properties

Answer (score 0):

If you're mapping to Java 8, you can use:

```
    val kotlinModule = KotlinModule.Builder()
        .disable(KotlinFeature.StrictNullChecks)
        .build()
    val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
    objectMapper.registerModules(
        Jdk8Module(),
        kotlinModule
    )
```